# Is there a bug in the design of PipedInputStream.java or have I misunderstood its design?

Tags: java

I have a problem related to `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`, and I don't know if I have misunderstood the design of these classes or if there is a bug in the java code in `PipedInputStream.java`

As far as I understand `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` implement a mechanism that can be used to create a stream between two different threads. A producer thread writes something in the `PipedOutputStream` and a consumer thread reads it in the connected `PipedInputStream`. There is an internal buffer to allow a buffered communication. By default the size of this buffer is 1024 bytes.

If the consumer thread reads the `PipedInputStream` and the buffer is empty, then the thread waits. If the producer thread writes the `PipedOutputStream` and the buffer is full, then the thread also waits.

`PipedInputStream` maintains the internal buffer, `PipedOutputStream` only uses functions declared in `PipedInputStream`.

All the fields related with the internal (circular) buffer in `PipedInputStream` (the `byte [] buffer`, the `int in` and the `int out` -as you can see in `PipedInputStream.java`) are all declared `protected`. `PipedInputStream` injects data using 2 different  `PipedInputStream.receive` functions.

All InputStreams has two read versions: `read()` and `read(byte [], int, int)`. All OutputStreams has two write versions `write(byte b)` and `write(byte [], int, int)`. All have a single-byte version and a multi-byte version. `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` have these functions.

`PipedOutputStream.write(byte b)` uses `PipedInputStream.receive(int b)` function to inject the byte in the connected `PipedInputStream`. This receive function is declared `protected` so you can overload this function and intercept any byte injection from `PipedOutputStream` to the connected `PipedInputStream`.

`PipedOutputStream.write(byte b[], int offset, int len)` uses `PipedInputStream.receive(byte [] b, int offset, int len)` to inject an array of bytes in the connected `PipedInputStream`.

And here comes my problem: `PipedInputStream.receive(byte [], int, int)`, the multi-byte counterpart of `receive(int)`,  is not declared protected as `receive(int)` is, it has the default visibility (package visibility). So you cannot overload this function and intercept multibytes injection from `PipedOutputStream` to the connected `PipedInputStream`.

`PipedInputStream.write(byte b[], int offset, int len)` does not invoke `PipedInputStream.write(int b)`. So overloading `receive(int)` has no effect when using `receive(byte [],int, int)`.

As far as I understand, `PipedInputStream.receive(byte[], int, int)` should be `protected` as `PipedInputStream.receive(int)` is. Its declaration:

`synchronized void receive(byte [] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {`

should be:

`protected synchronized void receive(byte [] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {`

`PipeReader` and `PipeWriter` (the character version of `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`) declare the buffer fields and the receive method with package visibility (not protected!). Reader/Writer (since JDK1.1) in Java are newer than InputStream/OutputStream (since JDK1.0).

Is it a real bug in the design of `PipedInputStream`?, is the `protected` visibity in `PipedInputStream` a design accident inherited from earlier Java versions?, or or am I completely lost?.

Thanks in advance.

PD: Here is an example where this problem appears. This program does not compile (by the mentioned receive visibility problem). In this example I try to create a `PipedInputStream` subclass that allows the automatic extension of the buffer when needed. So, if buffer is empty and someone try to read the thread waits. But if buffer is full and someone try to write (using the connected `PipedOutputStream`) the thread does not wait, but the buffer is extended to store more bytes. Consumers wait but producers don't.

I have my own functional implementations of this example, but I wanted to know if it cannot be implemented as a `PipedInputStream` subclass.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;

public class ExtensiblePipedInputStream extends PipedInputStream {

/**
 * Default extensions' size
 */
private static final int DEFAULT_EXTENSION = 1024;

/**
 * The current extensions' size
 */
protected int extension = DEFAULT_EXTENSION;


// the same constructors than the super class (PipedInputStream)...

public ExtensiblePipedInputStream() {
    super();
}

public ExtensiblePipedInputStream(PipedOutputStream src) throws IOException {
    super(src);
}

public ExtensiblePipedInputStream(int pipeSize) {
    super(pipeSize);
}

public ExtensiblePipedInputStream(PipedOutputStream src, int pipeSize) throws IOException {
    super(src, pipeSize);
}

/**
 * This function ensures the specified capacity in the internal buffer. If
 * the specified capacity is less or equals than the current internal buffer
 * capacity it does nothing. If the specified capacity is greater than the
 * current one, then the buffer is extended to: at least allocate the new
 * capacity. This function extends the buffer using multiple factors of
 * extension size.
 *
 * @param capacity The capacity
 * @throws IOException if an IO error occurs
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if capacity is negative
 */
public synchronized void ensureCapacity(int capacity) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
    if (capacity < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity < 0");
    }

    if (capacity > buffer.length) {
        int additionalSpace = capacity - buffer.length;
        final int modExtension = additionalSpace % extension;
        additionalSpace += (modExtension == 0) ? 0 : extension - modExtension;

        setCapacity(buffer.length + additionalSpace);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns capacity of the internal buffer (the buffer's size).
 *
 * @return The capacity or the internal buffer
 */
public synchronized int getCapacity() {
    return buffer.length;
}

/**
 * Returns the size of the next buffer's extensions.
 *
 * @return The size of the next buffer's extensions.
 */
public synchronized int getExtension() {
    return extension;
}

/**
 * This function extends and invokes PipedInputStream.receive. It only avoid
 * writers block by extending the internal buffer when needed.
 *
 * @param b The byte to be received
 * @throws IOException if an IO error occurs
 */
@Override
protected synchronized void receive(int b) throws IOException {
    ensureCapacity(available() + 1);
    super.receive(b);
}

/**
 * MY PROBLEM!!!!
 * 
 * this function is not posible!
 * 
 * PipedInputStream.receive(byte[], int, int)
 * has not protected visibility, it has package visibility!!!!!
 * 
 * Why?
 * 
 * @param b The array of bytes to be received
 * @param off The offset in the array of bytes.
 * @param len The number of bytes to be received.
 * @throws IOException If an IO error occurs
 */
@Override
protected synchronized void receive(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    ensureCapacity(available() + len);
    super.receive(b, off, len);
}

/**
 * Changes the size of the internal buffer. The new size must be greater or
 * equals than the number of bytes stored in the internal buffer
 * (available())
 *
 * @param capacity The new size of the internal buffer.
 * @throws IOException If an IO error occurs.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If capacity < available()
 */
public synchronized void setCapacity(int capacity) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException {
    final int available = available();

    if (capacity < available) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity < available");
    }

    final byte[] nbuf = new byte[capacity];
    if (available > 0) {
        final int firstTransferAmount = Math.min(available, buffer.length - out);
        System.arraycopy(buffer, out, nbuf, 0, firstTransferAmount);
        if (in > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, nbuf, firstTransferAmount, in);
        }
        out = 0;
        in = (available == capacity) ? 0 : available;
    }

    buffer = nbuf;
}

/**
 * Set the size of future extensions. It must be a value greater than 0.
 *
 * @param extension The size of future extensions.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException If extension <= 0
 */
public synchronized void setExtension(int extension) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (extension <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("extension <= 0");
    }

    this.extension = extension;
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to extend the piped stream?  Why not make it large enough that you never need to grow it?

Comment: Let say you spent 2 hours on this, this would be about $20 at minimum wage.  If you decided to "waste" 128KB in a buffer which didn't really need it. It would be wasting 0.2 cents of memory. Please tell me you are planning to use millions of these ;)

Comment: These classes were not designed for extension and in the very early days of Java the designers were not as sensitized to these concerns so an unneeded `protected` access level may have slipped by. You should refrain from trying to extend any JDK class except for those which clearly document the contract for their subclasses.

Comment: Buffer size is not uniform in time, generally low occupation but with high size peaks. It is not possible to maintain the memory allocated. Buffer could be empty or it can store MBytes. I can have hundred of producers/consumers running simultaneously. As I have my own implementation from scratch, I was wondering if it is possible to implement as a PipedInputStream subclass.

Comment: Why do you need to expand the buffer at any point?  If you have more data to send through the pipe than fits in the buffer, send it through in buffer sized chunks.  This is how streams are supposed to work in Java.

Comment: Thanks Louis for your interest. The problem I see in the design of PipedInputStream is that both, your solution and my solution, are not possible to implement “in a reasonable way”. It is irrelevant if I extend the array, maintain a list of arrays or create a completely new storage structure in PipedInputStream. The problem in the design (as far as I can see) is that PipedOutputStream writes the data using a function that the subclass cannot overload.  I can create a very sophisticated PipedInputStream but it will never intercept the invocation of receive(byte [],int, int).

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood the purpose of pipes. Pipes are for **blocking** communication between two different threads. The speed of the writer is expected to be limited to the speed of the reader which means a pipe is efficient in memory usage, but limits processing to the speed of the slowest component.

If you want asynchronous writing you should look at using a Queue - one of the versions in the java.util.concurrent package should suit.

Comment: PipedInputStream mention limits in the decoupling of read/write operations. But it does not mention that the limits should be constant in time. PipedInputStream.java code says that pipe size was allowed to change in the declaration of "int the protected static final int PIPE_SIZE" there is a comment that says: This used to be a constant before the pipe size was allowed to change. This field will continue to be maintained for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

An API design that does not support a particular use-case (especially one that involves subclassing) could be described as "limited" or "restricted" ... but it is a stretch to call this a bug.

If we accept the dubious proposition<sup>1</sup> that what you are trying to implement is worthwhile, then I think your analysis is correct.  Creating a version of the piped input / output streams with expandable buffers is more work than it would be if the modifiers were different.

But ... it is not impossible.  You can achieve what you want by a more large-scale overriding of methods (e.g. the `read` and `write` methods), or by simply starting from scratch.

---

The other thing to note is that this (StackOverflow) is not the right place to report Java "bugs" or make requests for enhancement.  If you really feel strongly about this, try developing and submitting a patch with your proposed change to the OpenJDK team.  But bear in mind that anything that breaks compatibility (including compatibility with existing customer subclasses of `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`) is likely to be rejected.  This could this might explain why they haven't "fixed" this already!

---

<sup>1 - As Barry points out, the piped streams are blocking by design.  A non-blocking version is potentially dangerous.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your response, but how can a subclass of of PipedInputStream intercept the receive(byte[], int, int) invocation done by PipedOutputStream?. You must note that the write operation is not in PipedInputStream, so it cannot be overloaded by a subclass of PipedInputStream. If I need to create a subclass X of PipedOutputStream to deal with the subclass Y of PipedInputStream, then Y is not a PipedInputStream (cause it cannot be used by any PipedOutputStream). The problem in the design, as far as I can see, is that it is not possible to do it as a PipedInputStream subclass.

Comment: I think it is possible to create a subclass of PipedInputStream that intercepts the invocation of its hidden/forbidden receive method using the Java Platform Debugger Architecture [JPDA] (the new subclass will be declared as a debugger in the JVM TI, and it can intercept the receive invocation; the class will debug itself!). But I think this is not a “reasonable way” (and it is also a very, very ugly thing).

Comment: *"how can a subclass of of PipedInputStream intercept ..."*.  It can't.  JPDA won't work either - a running application can't use JPDA against itself (AFAIK).  Do it a different way.  Override the `read` and `write` methods etcetera.

Comment: Stephen, thanks again for your time and your interest. As I mentioned I have my own solution (non using PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream), the key of my question only concerns the PipedInputStream design. I think than both receive methods must have the same visibility. No matter if both are protected (a permisive solution) or package-level (a restrited solution), but I think both must have the same visibility (this is, I think, a possible design bug -but it is not a functional bug).

Comment: _"...JPDA won't work either - a running application can't use JPDA against itself (AFAIK)..."_.  Gerard Davison, wrote a entry blog called “Write an auto-debugger to catch Exceptions during test execution” showing that a Java process can be simultaneously debugger and debugged in the same JVM. So, it could be possible to create a Java class that overrides any method invocation in any object (including those methods with private level). Thanks again for your interest.